# How do I edit elements under Properties for an Element in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am learning Chrome Dev Tools and following author John Sonmez for the same.
As an example: I tried to modify "alt:" element for my example image.

Steps to produce:
Right click on an image then Inspect it and, click on Elements tab, we can see Styles, Computed, Properties etc tabs on right side, and try to modify elements under Properties tab.

I was able to modify elements under Styles tab, however everything seem frozen under Properties tab.
I tried same by going into incognito mode, but nothing works.

Comment: It's a read-only panel.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. May be video which I am following is quite old. I now updated the desired property directly inline of the element, inside Elements tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm: if you post it as an answer, I would accept that to close this thread